# Is there a way to make http request without being banned?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I want to do some **scraping** n the website odmiana.net. However I am banned only after a few request (4 or 6). These requests are spaced in time

robots.txt :

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://odmiana.net/sitemap.xml.gz
```

current code:

```rb
require 'rest_client'

response = RestClient.get 'https://odmiana.net/'
```

I don't understand why am I detected as a robot and how not to be.
Someone has an idea?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to tell us what is the delay between your 4-6 requests?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The delay is 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do as many request I want, thanks to the following code:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
10.times do
  driver.get 'https://odmiana.net/'
  sleep 3
end
```